# Excel VBA For loop with UsedRange Count Error

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, iteration

```
maxRow = ws.UsedRange.EntireRow.Count

For n = 1 To maxRow

    Do While Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("D" & n).Value)
    
    ws.Range("D" & n & ":" & "E" & n).Delete shift:=xlShiftToLeft
    Rows(n + 1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
    maxRow = maxRow + 1
    
    Loop

Next n
```

I was just wondering why my code always exit when n = 19 (number of original maxRow count). I added maxRow = maxRow +1 because I inserted one row so that it doesn't exit until it is finished.

What I am trying to do, is to remove the two cells (D&E) and inserting a row underneath until D&E is empty.

Thanks

Comment: When deleting or inserting loop backwards. Also you shouldn't need both a For-Next and Do-While loop.

Comment: So, the desired result will be D:E cells deleted (replaces by the ones of the right) and an empty row below each such a processed row. Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

You did not answer my question and I prepared an answer based on the assumption that the necessary code must replace the cells in D:E with their right neighbors (F:G) and insert a row after such a processed range. If this assumption is correct, please test the next code:

```
Sub testDeleteRangeInsertRow()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, n As Long
 
 Set ws = ActiveSheet

   n = 2
    Do While Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("D" & n).value)
    
       ws.Range("D" & n & ":" & "E" & n).Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
       Rows(n + 1).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
       n = n + 2
    Loop
End Sub
```

If my assumption is wrong, please better explain (in words...) what do you need to accomplish...

Comment: @Michael Norman: Did you find some time to test the above code? At least to answer the clarification question, if the code, does not do what you really need, reflecting only my understanding...